# Поясните смысл примера из учебника по Java 8

Tags: java

Почему я должен делать ссылку каждый раз `figref = r; figref.area()`? Почему нельзя просто написать r.area()?

```
class FindAreas {
    pubic static void main(String args[]) {
        Figure f = new Figure(lO, 10); 
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(9, 5); 
        Triangle t = new Triangle(lO, 8); 
        Figure figre;
        figref = r;
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + figref.area() ) ;
        figref = t;
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + figref.area() ) ;
        figref = f;
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + figref.area() ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Эм... А зачем вы так делаете???

Comment: Книга Shildt Java 8. Все программы  для примеров так пишутся и я просто не понимаю почему и зачем. Явно же не просто так.

Comment: Так глава наверное об интерфейсах?

Comment: абстрактные классы

Comment: Странный контекст, если это так, но да ладно.

Comment: Видимо, этот пример наглядно демонстрирует, что в переменную `figref` вы можете поместить объект любого типа, лишь бы он был наследником класса `Figure` (или интерфейса), в котором есть метод `area()`. Практического смысла — никакого, это лишь пример, а в реальности код выглядел бы так, как вам написали в ответах

Answer (score 2):

Так и не надо... Я так понимаю интерфейс один? Весь ваш код можно сократить до:

```
class FindAreas {
    pubic static void main(String args[]){
        Figure f = new Figure(10, 10);
        Figure r = new Rectangle(9, 5);
        Figure t = new Triangle(10, 8);

        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + f.area());
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + r.area());
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + t.area());
    }
}
```

Или:

```
class FindAreas {
    pubic static void main(String args[]){
        Figure f = new Figure(10, 10);

        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + f.area());

        f = new Rectangle(9, 5);
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + f.area());

        f = new Triangle(10, 8);
        System.out.println("Плoщaдь равна " + f.area());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это пример, как я понимаю, рассказывает о наследовании и приведении типов.
Все три класса `Figure`, `Rectangle`, `Triangle` - являются наследниками одного базового класса (или интерфейса я уж не знаю) `Figure`. У этого интерфейса имеется метод `area()` вычисляющий какую-то величину (в примере - площадь). 
Пример демонстрирует, что все эти классы можно привести к единому общему классу `Figure` и вызвать его метод, который также будет присутствовать во всех его "потомках"